# using tcomb form native in react native

Tags: react-native, tcomb-form-native

I am using `tcomb` to build a form in `react-native`, a field in my form is `birthDate: t.maybe(t.Date)`, but it appears to have no style

```
const formRegistration = t.struct({
   // other fields
   birthDate: t.maybe(t.Date)
});
```

[image]

I have also added `config` down the `options`:

```
const options = {
  fields : {
     birthDate: {
        label: 'Birth Date',
        mode: 'date',
        config: { 
           format: (date) => myFormatFunction('DD MM YYYY', date),
           dialogMode: 'spinner'
        }
     }
   }
 }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this: https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form-native/blob/master/lib/stylesheets/bootstrap.js
The style for the date is in `dateValue` at line 196

so this is what I did to style it according to the need:

```
const Form = t.form.Form;

Form.stylesheet.dateValue.normal.borderColor = '#d0d2d3';
Form.stylesheet.dateValue.normal.backgroundColor = '#f0f1f1';
Form.stylesheet.dateValue.normal.borderWidth = 1;
```

you follow the same way to style other key parts in tcomb (e.g: labels: `Form.stylesheet.controlLabel.normal.fontSize = 14;`)